# How can I explain signifcant combined groups in Mann Whitney U but no individual effects in Kruskal Wallis?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I am struggling to get my head around the concepts of my tests and how to explain them. Unfortunately we didn't recieve much in depth teaching about it on my course.

I have 4 variables, one is a control. When I combine the 3 experimental conditions to compare with the control(all should have some similar effect) I get a signifcant MW-U test of p = 0.22. Mdn scores 2.3 vs 1.9

Overall Mdn sores are 2.2, 2.2, 2.7 and 1.9 for the groups with control being the smallest.
However, in my KW there is no signifcant effect at all, where I'd have expected to see something for the 2.7 compared to the 1.9? given my MWU.

How does this work please ? and is there any way I can report this without commiting a crime against science? It seems logical one of them is signifcant (2.7) and the 2.2 groups are not. Combined the larger group just helps the others out a bit.

Are there better ways to compare these groups?

Thank you in advance !(and I appreciate the question doesn't fully make sense , I'm confused)

Comment: 1) The MWU and KW tests don't actually test for differences in the medians in most cases.  They test if one group is likely to have observations with higher values than the other group.  You could perform other tests if you were interested in testing the medians.  2)  Really you would want to decide ahead of time whether you are interested in using WMU to compare treatment to control, or if you are interested in treating the treatments as separate groups with KW. (con't).

Comment: 3) It's probably fairly unusual to get the different results you did from KW and WMU, but I was able to come up with an example pretty quickly.  The difference in results is likely connected to having a larger sample size when you pool the groups.  3b) For those interested, try:  Treat =  "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"; Value = 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 3.4 4.5 5.5 , where A is the control treatment.